# What happened to the voting buttons?

Tags: support, design, ios

Starting from yesterday, the up-/downvote buttons seem to have moved from the left of a post towards above (in the middle) of the bodies of all questions and answers.

Here is a screenprint of a sample (containing such buttons for both a question and an answer to it):

> [image]

This happens on an iOS device (running 9.3.5), using various browsers and this in any SE site. No idea so far how it looks like in the most recent iOS version.

Same for the (green) checkbox below those voting buttons (to mark an answer as accepted).

**Is this intended to be like this (IMO it looks ugly ... and a huge waste of available space), or is it rather some sort of CSS related issue that needs to be fixed?**

PS: Looking at the same page around the same time on a Win PC (using any of the common browsers) seems to work fine.

Comment: This should only happen if you're using an old browser that does not support grid layout.

Comment: Related question on Meta.SO: [Arrows and counter for upvotes/downvotes were on the left, and are now centered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391887/4751173)